# Edit value of variable in Arduino memory

Tags: arduino

i am trying to change the variable's value with button. I declared the variable before the setup() method:

```
const int button = 14;

float minimum_temp = 37.7;
```

and the way to change the variable is (in loop() method):

```
buttonState = digitalRead(button);

if (buttonState != lastButtonState){
   if (buttonState == HIGH){
      minimum_temp -= 0.1;
      //i expect same command here
   }
   delay(50);
}
```

My question is, how can i save changed minimum_temp to flash memory. I need, when i restart my Arduino, get the last minimum_temp setting.

Comment: [EEPROM Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM)

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you.